# Как задать переменную в скрипте bash, чтоб она сохранялась при использование цикла?

Tags: bash

Я практикуюсь в написании bash скриптов и у меня возникла проблема, при выполнение моего скрипта "/myscript.sh /firstpath/* /secondpath" все переменные базовые {1-9} переопределяются в цикле.
У меня есть такой скрипт

```
#! /bin/bash

# Берёт путь из переменной №1 и копирует от туда все файлы по пути переменной №2 добавляя при этом в название дату и время создания файла

Dirend=${2}

echo ${1}
echo ${2}

for i in ${1}; do bname=$(basename $i);suf=$(ls -l $i | awk '{print $6,$7,$8}'| sed 's/ /_/g')| sed 's_/__'; cp ${i} ${Dirend}/${bname}_${suf}; done
```

В итоге я получаю такой ответ.

```
/home/test/firstpath/file#2.txt
/home/test/firstpath/file#1.txt

cp: failed to access '/home/test/firstpath/file#2.txt/file#1.txt_': Not a directory
```

Я относительно понял почему так происходит. По моему представлению просто переменные {1-9} являются ссылочными и переопределяются в цикле, но как это реализовать по другому информации не нашел пока что.

Comment: Что-то я так и не понял что должен делать этот скрипт? Что у него на входе?

Comment: Берёт первым аргументом путь папки из которой нужно скопировать все файлы и вторым аргументом путь папки в которую нужно скопировать все эти файлы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

для точности формулировок дальше параметрами я буду называть то, что указывается в команде при вызове скрипта, а аргументами то, что получает скрипт при выполнении. да, эти две сущности могут не совпадать, как в описанном в вопросе случае.

---

сначала про ошибки:

1. `for i in ${1}; do ...; done` — такой цикл отработает ноль (если параметров скрипту вообще не передавалось) либо один раз (только для первого из аргументов).
2. так как в каталоге `firstpath` у вас находится несколько файлов/каталогов, то конструкция `firstpath/*`, переданная как параметр, будет преобразована в несколько аргументов, по одному аргументу на каждый файл/каталог, имя которого соответствует маске `firstpath/*`. соответственно, у вашего скрипта будет плавающее количество аргументов, и целевой каталог надо извлекать из списка аргументов именно как *последний* аргумент, а не просто как *второй по порядку*.
3. (завуалированная ошибка) не стоит парсить вывод программы `ls`, запущенной с опцией `-l`: формат вывода там «плавающий», для чтения человеком. а для машинной обработки информацию из inode файла/каталога лучше получать программой *stat*.

---

теперь про исправление:

1. получить последний аргумент, переданный скрипту, можно [разными способами](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1853946/4827341). например (для программы *bash* версии >= 3.0):

   ```
   last=${BASH_ARGV[0]}
   ```
2. пройтись циклом по всем аргументам кроме последнего можно [разными способами](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20398499/4827341). например:

   ```
   for i in "${@:1:$(($#-1))}"; do ...; done
   ```
3. программой *stat* можно получить время модификации файла(-ов)/каталога(-ов) в виде количества секунд с начала эпохи:

   ```
   $ stat -c '%Y' файлы каталоги ...
   ```

   преобразовать это значение в дату/время можно с помощью программы *date*:

   ```
   $ date -d @1630581630 +"%F_%T"
   2021-09-02_11:20:30
   ```